# Clean way to force view to load subviews early

Tags: ios, uiview, uiviewcontroller

Recently I wrote some code where I tried to refer to an outlet on a `UIViewController` I'd just instantiated with `[storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier]` and modify the subview that the outlet pointed to before presenting the `ViewController`. It didn't work because the `ViewController`'s view hadn't loaded its subviews yet, including the one that my outlet referred to, so the property just gave me a null pointer.

After (with some struggle) tracking down the cause of my issue in the debugger, I Googled around and learned, through answers like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1935526/make-a-view-initialized-from-initwithnibname-load-all-its-subview), that I can cause the view to load its subviews without being displayed by calling the `myViewController.view` getter. After that, I can access my outlet without any problems.

It's a clear hack, though, and Xcode - quite rightly - doesn't like it, and angrily protests with this warning:

> Property access result unused - getters should not be used for side effects

Is there a non-hacky alternative way to do this that doesn't involved abusing the `.view` getter? Alternatively, are there canonical/idiomatic patterns for this scenario involving something like dynamically adding a handler to be called as soon as the subviews are loaded?

Or is the standard solution just to replace `myViewController.view` with `[myViewController view]` to shut up Xcode's warning, and then live with the hack?

Comment: You can change any obj.property to [obj property] to stop that warning.  There's no difference between an ObjC getter and a selector with no arguments.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

On iOS 9 or newer, one can use:

```
viewController.loadViewIfNeeded()
```

Docs: https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621446-loadviewifneeded

Comment: This is the answer that most directly answers the question asked and gets my checkmark, but note that in many cases it may be misguided - consider [moving whatever logic you need the view loaded for into `viewDidLoad`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18172365/1709587) instead.

Comment: @MarkAmery It may or it may not. :)

Answer (score 6):

I agree that forcing a view to load should be avoided but I ran into a case where it seemed the only reasonable solution to a problem (popping a UINavigationController containing a UISearchController that had yet to be invoked causes a nasty console says warning).

What I did was use new iOS9 API loadViewIfNeeded and for pre-iOS9 used viewController.view.alpha = 1.0. Of course a good comment above this code will prevent you (or someone else) removing this code later thinking it is unneeded.

The fact that Apple is now providing this API signals it can be needed from time to time.

Answer (score 3):

Not sure how much cleaner this way, but it still works fine:

```
_ = vc.view
```

UPD: for your convenience, you can declare extension like below:

```
extension UIViewController {
    func preloadView() {
        let _ = view
    }
}
```

You can read explaination by following URL: https://www.natashatherobot.com/ios-testing-view-controllers-swift/

Answer (score 2):

merged Rudolph/Swany answers for pre ios9 deployment targets

```
    if #available(iOS 9.0, *) {
        loadViewIfNeeded()
    }
    else {
        // _ = self.view works but some Swift compiler genius could optimize what seems like a noop out
        // hence this perversion from this recipe http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17279604/clean-way-to-force-view-to-load-subviews-early
        view.alpha = 1
    }
```

Comment: I don't think that would ever be optimized out because while the result is unused, one can't make the assumption it's a non-op since this doesn't give you any information about what the getter does internally so I'd argue it's a safe assumption it will never be removed via optimization.

Comment: probably you are right but i've come to expect the worst from the swift compiler contributors

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, I think there's another fairly standard solution: move the outlet modification/configuration code into a `viewDidLoad` method (of the recently instantiated VC).

The topic is also discussed in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11724003/why-uilabel-is-not-initialized).

It would require some restructuring, but it might give you a "cleaner" design in terms of MVC if your incoming VC handled its own configuration, and it would avoid the "You should never call this method directly" stricture on `loadView`.

Comment: D'oh. Yep, this is how I ought to have been doing it all along.

Comment: Although I've read contradictory claims about whether `viewDidLoad` can be called more than once - so it may be worth having in `BOOL isInitialized` ivar that's used to ensure that initialization code in `viewDidLoad` is only ever executed one time (if necessary).

Answer (score -2):

You can call `[myViewController loadView]` to explicitly load the view, instead of abusing the `.view` getter. The `.view` getter actually calls `loadView` if necessary when called.

It's still not a very nice solution, since the [UIView Documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html)'s section on `loadView` explicitly instructs that

> You should never call this method directly

Comment: Credit to zbMax for this answer; he posted it as a comment, but it's a complete answer to the question.

Comment: The safe way to do this, as the docs tell you nowadays, is to call `[myViewController view]` instead -- invoking that getter will do the `loadView` call _the correct way_ behind the scenes.