# Unit Testing Storyboard viewDidLoad not called

Tags: ios, objective-c, unit-testing, uiviewcontroller, storyboard

So there are a few articles floating about on how to load a Storyboard containing a nib for unit testing and it looks something like this

```
MyViewController vc;

- (void)setUp
{
    [super setUp];
    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
    self.vc = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"main"];
    [self.vc performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(loadView) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:YES];
}
```

However when i do it the `viewDidLoad` method of the class is never called and i have to do it manually like so

```
- (void)setUp
{
    [super setUp];
    // Put setup code here. This method is called before the invocation of each test method in the class.

    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MediaSelectionSuite" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
    SUT = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Gallery"];
    [SUT performSelectorOnMainThread:NSSelectorFromString(@"loadView") withObject:nil waitUntilDone:YES];
    [SUT viewDidLoad];
}
```

As you can see i have to add `[SUT viewDidLoad];` for `viewDidLoad` of the controller to be called at all...It works, and i should not worry too much since it's a suite of tests but i have misgivings about it since you should rarely have to call it manually, and shouldn't either `instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:` or the selector to call `loadView` make sure `viewDidLoad` is called?

**UPDATE**

After a bit of experimentation it seems that only the `UIViewController` which has been set to be your storyboards initial `UIViewController` has it's `viewDidLoad` method called on `instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:`

Comment: Could post the entire code in `viewDidLoad`?

Answer (score 1):

I've recently come across the same situation as you and found my solution. You are correct viewDidLoad() is not called automatically. In fact, you can call the view property of the view controller to trigger viewDidLoad(). For more information checkout out [View Controller TDD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28733016/view-controller-tdd)