# Make a unit test wait for a async call inside another method

Tags: ios, swift, unit-testing, xctest

I'm testing that all my data are correctly loaded in a `UIViewController` with a `UITableView`.

The code loading the data and populating the table is inside `myMethod()` and its an an async call.

```
func myMethod() {
    reloadModel { ... wait for async callback ... }
}
```

In my Test Case, I'm calling `myMethod()`, but I don't know how to wait for the async call to complete.

```
//Test Code
func testLoadData() {
        let listVC = ListViewController.init(tableView:tableView)
        listVC .myMethod()
         ... here it should wait for the async call...
        XCTAssertEqual(...)
}
```

Comment: The test is not meaningful anyway because you must not call any delegate method which includes `did`, `will` and `should`. Those methods are called by the framework to inform about a particular stage of the workflow. I doubt that there is a significant difference in an unit test.

Comment: @vadian ok lets be more specific then. I've updated the question. Lets say I have a random method myMethod() now.

Comment: There is no such option. You should think about how to abstract your "model provider" class and inject dependency into your viewContorller

Comment: @AntonBelousov I see why approach is wrong now. Ok thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The issue is that you're trying to test too much. Your test of `myMethod()` should not be asserting that the data is fetched (you shouldn't be doing networking in unit tests). It should test that the view controller calls the right method on its data fetcher helper. Which means that you need to create a seam there, and then mock out that fetcher object.

Then there's no waiting in your view controller test; you just assert that `myMethod()` triggers a call to `pleaseGoGetMyData()` on the mock.

Then you test the data fetcher separately, again mocking out its dependency on the networking stack so that all you need to test is that the fetcher makes the right request and that it returns the right (dummy) data to its client.

Failing that, to do async tests, you'll need to use [`XCTestExpectation`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/xctest/xctestexpectation). See [EridB's answer to a related question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40202741/603977) for an example.