# UILabel.text doesn't add the the NSString and stays null

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilabel

I wanted to add a string to a label and tried different things.

So this is what my code looks like:

```
@interface DeviceControl : UIViewController

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *intensityLevelView;
@property (weak, nonatomic) UILabel *intensityLabel;

- (IBAction)intensitySliderDragged:(id)sender

@end

@synthesize intensityLabel;
@synthesize intensityLevelView;

- (IBAction)intensitySliderDragged:(id)sender {

intensityLevel = intensitySlider.value;

int newIntensityLevel = (int)intensityLevel; //because intensityLevel is a float and I needed an integer.
intensityLabel = (UILabel*)[intensityLevelView viewWithTag:10];
NSString *string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Intensity is at %d",newIntensityLevel];
intensityLabel.text = string;
NSLog(@"string = %@", string);
NSLog(@"label text = %@",intensityLabel.text);
}
```

That didn't work so I tried these too:

```
intensityLabel.text = [intensityLabel.text stringByAppendingFormat:@"%d",newIntensityLevel];

intensityLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Intensity is at %d", newIntensityLevel];
```

And I was so frustrated that I even tried this if that worked:

```
intensityLabel.text = @"damn"; //it didn't worked...
```

My console prints

> 2017-04-19 10:47:58.849359+0800 string = Intensity is at 100
>
> 2017-04-19 10:47:58.849484+0800 label text = (null)

So what am I doing wrong? Why the label.text stays null?

Comment: Have you tried `[intensityLabel setText:@"hello"]`

Comment: Can you show where you print the label value to console?

Comment: Yes I tried this one too, forgot to add it because I deleted because it didn't worked.

Comment: I printed it at the last line : NSLog(@"label text = %@",intensityLabel.text);

Comment: Any of these ways should have worked. So the last thing I would say is that your `intensityLabel` is not correctly hooked up. Can you check if its value is `nil`?

Comment: The problem is simple - `intensityLabel` is `nil`. Do some debugging to see why.

Comment: Yes it is nil, how can I fix that?

Comment: Either your `intensityLevelView` is nil as well. Or it doesn't have any view with `tag:10`

Comment: Yeah... Both of them are nil, but I added a view with a tag.

Comment: If `intensityLevelView` is `nil` then you never connected your outlet.

Comment: did you check tag of intensityLabel or **is it subview of intensityLevelView** ?

Comment: So, I connected the intensityLevelView with my outlet (stupid error of mine). The intensityLabel isn't nil anymore but has the value of intensityLevelView. And I get the error in my console -[UIView setText:]: unrecognized selector send to instance.

Comment: So I found this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11724003/why-uilabel-is-not-initialized and read the answer and the link and I didn't get it at all...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution to my problem...

I just needed to add one line to the -(void)viewdDidLoad {} and this is it:

```
[self.intensityLabel addSubview:intensityLevelView];
```

Answer (score 0):

Breakpoint on `intensityLabel = (UILabel *) [intensityLevelView viewWithTag: 10]`. The next line to see if `intensityLabel` is empty. Could be a tag is wrong.

Comment: I know why it says that it's null, intensityLabel and intensityLabelView are both nil

Comment: Need to check whether your xib associated, you post code didn't see the initialization process